# Criar uma VIEW ou uma nova TABELA no Postgres?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql, tabela-banco-de-dados, view

Olás!
Estou com uma situação...
Tenho uma tabela que terá cerca de 3*10^12 linhas (3 trilhões), porém, com apenas 3 atributos.
Nessa tabela terá os IDs de 2 indivíduos e a semelhança entre eles (é um número entre 0 e 1 que multipliquei por 100 e coloquei como um smallint para diminuir o espaço).
Acontece que preciso realizar, para determinado indivíduo que quero fazer a pesquisa, a sumarização dessas colunas e retornando quantos indivíduos tem até 10% de semelhança, 20%, 30%... Esses valores são fixos (de 10 em 10), até chegar em indivíduos idênticos.
Porém, como devem saber, a consulta será muito lenta, então, pensei em:
- Criar uma nova tabela para guardar os valores sumarizados
- Criar uma view para guardar esses valores.
Como os indivíduos são cerca de 1.7 milhões, a busca não seria tão demorada (se indexada, retorna bem rápido). Então, o que posso fazer?
Saliento que essa minha população será praticamente fixa (após o BD ser totalmente populado, espera-se que seja feito quase nenhum acréscimo).

Comment: essa tabela que tem 3 trilhoes sofre algum tipo de update ou insert? é um valor estatıco?

Comment: Hudson: `"Saliento que essa minha população será praticamente fixa (após o BD ser totalmente populado, espera-se que seja feito quase nenhum acréscimo)"`. Só trabalharia com View se a query a ser executada for sempre a mesma, sem a necessidade de aplicar condições, caso contrário fica muito ruim. Acho que poderia ter uma nova tabela, que, com uma trigger faça a relação de semelhança para cada sujeito

Comment: Já pensou em criar índices baseados em expressões ? Parece ser o caso o o Postgreesql parece suportar https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/indexes-expressional.html

Comment: @HudsonPH, essa tabela não sofrerá updates, porém, terá inserts sempre que um novo indivíduo for inserido na lista de indivíduos (depois da tabela criada e totalmente populada, pode ser necessária a inserção de um ou outro hit, mas raramente).

Comment: @Motta, vou estudar essa possibilidade. Por enquanto eu criei 2 índices: um para cada coluna de indivíduo (para achá-los em meio à lista imensa).

Comment: @RovannLinhalis. então, pelo que eu entendi, para você, uma view não seria interessante por ter que ficar sempre fazendo consultas novas a cada vez que eu for executar (tipo, querendo sempre alterando qual indivíduo eu quero retornar), certo?
Agora, não entendi como a trigger seria útil.

Comment: se puder mostrar o exemplo do calculo da sua "sumarizacao", na resposta do lacobus comentei sobre a trigger

Answer (score 1):

No seu caso um índice poderia resolver perfeitamente o seu problema, sem a necessidade de criação de uma `VIEW`.

Assumindo que sua estrutura de dados seja algo como:

```
-- INDIVIDUO
CREATE TABLE tb_individuo
(
    id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    nome TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY( id )
);

-- SEMELHANCA
CREATE TABLE tb_semelhanca
(
    id_a BIGINT NOT NULL,
    id_b BIGINT NOT NULL,
    valor SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY( id_a, id_b ),
    FOREIGN KEY ( id_a ) REFERENCES tb_individuo ( id ),
    FOREIGN KEY ( id_b ) REFERENCES tb_individuo ( id )
);
```

Contendo os seguintes dados de exemplo:

```
-- INSERE 5 INDIVIDUOS
INSERT INTO tb_individuo ( id, nome ) VALUES ( 1, 'JOSE' );
INSERT INTO tb_individuo ( id, nome ) VALUES ( 2, 'JOAO' );
INSERT INTO tb_individuo ( id, nome ) VALUES ( 3, 'ANTONIO' );
INSERT INTO tb_individuo ( id, nome ) VALUES ( 4, 'MARIO' );
INSERT INTO tb_individuo ( id, nome ) VALUES ( 5, 'PEDRO' );

-- INSERE SEMELHANCAS ENTRE OS INDIVIDUOS 
INSERT INTO tb_semelhanca ( id_a, id_b, valor ) VALUES ( 1, 2, 5 );
INSERT INTO tb_semelhanca ( id_a, id_b, valor ) VALUES ( 1, 3, 13 );
INSERT INTO tb_semelhanca ( id_a, id_b, valor ) VALUES ( 1, 4, 27 );
INSERT INTO tb_semelhanca ( id_a, id_b, valor ) VALUES ( 1, 5, 98 );
INSERT INTO tb_semelhanca ( id_a, id_b, valor ) VALUES ( 2, 3, 54 );
INSERT INTO tb_semelhanca ( id_a, id_b, valor ) VALUES ( 2, 4, 63 );
INSERT INTO tb_semelhanca ( id_a, id_b, valor ) VALUES ( 2, 5, 77 );
INSERT INTO tb_semelhanca ( id_a, id_b, valor ) VALUES ( 3, 4, 85 );
INSERT INTO tb_semelhanca ( id_a, id_b, valor ) VALUES ( 3, 5, 42 );
INSERT INTO tb_semelhanca ( id_a, id_b, valor ) VALUES ( 4, 5, 33 );
```

Sugiro a criação de um índice no campo `valor` da tabela `tb_semelhanca`:

```
-- CRIACAO DE INDICE NO GRAU DE SEMELHANCA
CREATE INDEX ON tb_semelhanca ( valor );
```

O que possibilitaria consultas usando um `BETWEEN` para se recuper o intevalo desejado com bastante agilidade:

```
-- CONSULTA USANDO O INDICE
SELECT
    a.id,
    a.nome,
    b.id,
    b.nome,
    s.valor
FROM
    tb_semelhanca AS s
JOIN
    tb_individuo AS a ON ( a.id = s.id_a )
JOIN
    tb_individuo AS b ON ( b.id = s.id_b )
WHERE
    s.valor BETWEEN 20 AND 50;
```

Saída:

```
| id |    nome | id |  nome | valor |
|----|---------|----|-------|-------|
|  1 |    JOSE |  4 | MARIO |    27 |
|  4 |   MARIO |  5 | PEDRO |    33 |
|  3 | ANTONIO |  5 | PEDRO |    42 |
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/da827/1

**EDIT**

Se a necessidade de criação de um "sumário" for algo mandatório, ainda sim não vejo a necessidade de criação de uma `VIEW` ou tabela auxiliar.

Como a cardinalidade do `sumário` com a `semelhanca` seria de `1-para-1`, a simples criação de um campo na `tb_semelhanca` poderia resolver o problema, vejamos:

```
-- INDIVIDUO
CREATE TABLE tb_individuo
(
    id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    nome TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY( id )
);

-- SEMELHANCA
CREATE TABLE tb_semelhanca
(
    id_a BIGINT NOT NULL,
    id_b BIGINT NOT NULL,
    valor SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    sumario SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY( id_a, id_b ),
    FOREIGN KEY ( id_a ) REFERENCES tb_individuo ( id ),
    FOREIGN KEY ( id_b ) REFERENCES tb_individuo ( id )
);
```

O índice seria criado no campo `sumario` da `tb_semelhanca`:

```
-- CRIACAO DE INDICE NO sumario
CREATE INDEX ON tb_semelhanca ( sumario );
```

Uma `TRIGGER FUNCTION` seria responsavel pelo cálculo do sumário:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calcular_sumario() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$BODY$
BEGIN 
    NEW.sumario = (NEW.valor / 10)::int * 10; 
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Uma `TRIGGER` seria criada para disparar a função `calcular_sumario()` toda vez que acontencer uma modificação da `tb_semelhança`:

```
-- CRIANDO TRIGGER
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_sumario BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON tb_semelhanca FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE  calcular_sumario();
```

Populando tabelas:

```
-- INSERE 10 INDIVIDUOS
INSERT INTO tb_individuo ( id, nome ) VALUES ( 1, 'JOSE' );
INSERT INTO tb_individuo ( id, nome ) VALUES ( 2, 'JOAO' );
INSERT INTO tb_individuo ( id, nome ) VALUES ( 3, 'ANTONIO' );
INSERT INTO tb_individuo ( id, nome ) VALUES ( 4, 'MARIO' );
INSERT INTO tb_individuo ( id, nome ) VALUES ( 5, 'PEDRO' );

-- INSERE SEMELHANCAS ENTRE OS INDIVIDUOS 
INSERT INTO tb_semelhanca ( id_a, id_b, valor ) VALUES ( 1, 2, 5 );
INSERT INTO tb_semelhanca ( id_a, id_b, valor ) VALUES ( 1, 3, 13 );
INSERT INTO tb_semelhanca ( id_a, id_b, valor ) VALUES ( 1, 4, 27 );
INSERT INTO tb_semelhanca ( id_a, id_b, valor ) VALUES ( 1, 5, 98 );
INSERT INTO tb_semelhanca ( id_a, id_b, valor ) VALUES ( 2, 3, 54 );
INSERT INTO tb_semelhanca ( id_a, id_b, valor ) VALUES ( 2, 4, 63 );
INSERT INTO tb_semelhanca ( id_a, id_b, valor ) VALUES ( 2, 5, 77 );
INSERT INTO tb_semelhanca ( id_a, id_b, valor ) VALUES ( 3, 4, 85 );
INSERT INTO tb_semelhanca ( id_a, id_b, valor ) VALUES ( 3, 5, 42 );
INSERT INTO tb_semelhanca ( id_a, id_b, valor ) VALUES ( 4, 5, 33 );
```

Verificando `tb_semelhanca`:

```
| id_a | id_b | valor | sumario |
|------|------|-------|---------|
|    1 |    2 |     5 |       0 |
|    1 |    3 |    13 |      10 |
|    1 |    4 |    27 |      20 |
|    1 |    5 |    98 |      90 |
|    2 |    3 |    54 |      50 |
|    2 |    4 |    63 |      60 |
|    2 |    5 |    77 |      70 |
|    3 |    4 |    85 |      80 |
|    3 |    5 |    42 |      40 |
|    4 |    5 |    33 |      30 |
```

Consulta por meio do sumário:

```
-- CONSULTA USANDO O SUMARIO
SELECT
    a.id,
    a.nome,
    b.id,
    b.nome,
    s.valor
FROM
    tb_semelhanca AS s
JOIN
    tb_individuo AS a ON ( a.id = s.id_a )
JOIN
    tb_individuo AS b ON ( b.id = s.id_b )
WHERE
    s.sumario = 20;
```

Saída:

```
| id | nome | id |  nome | valor |
|----|------|----|-------|-------|
|  1 | JOSE |  4 | MARIO |    27 |
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/7e62f/5

Comment: acho que a questão seria calcular a 'sumarizacao' das semelhancas em uma view, ou armazena-las, em uma terceira tabela. Sugeri que fizesse a tabela de semelhança e uma trigger na tabela de indivíduos, para que, ao inserir ou alterar um individuo, sua semelhança seja recalculada. WandreVeloso, entendeu a proposta ? @Lacobus sempre com ótimas respostas sobre postgres =]

Comment: @RovannLinhalis Segue edição.

Comment: @Lacobus e RovannLinhalis, gostei muito da opção de acrescentar um novo campo indexado para agilizar a busca.
Creio que vou implementar dessa forma com criação de índices na primeira coluna (porque sempre quero saber a sumarização por determinado indivíduo) e na coluna sumarização.

Answer (score 0):

Tive o quase o mesmo problema, mas o meu banco chega ser bem maior que o seu e sofre updates e insert a cada minuto, a tabelas que passaram de 1gb eu usei partition baseado numa coluna relacionada a grupo.

A melhor solucao apos sua resposta nos comentarios, usar [Table partition](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/ddl-partitioning.html)

porque?
1 - vai dividir sua tabela em subtabelas e nao vai interfirir no
seu select(vai continuar o mesmo porem muito mas rapido).

2 - ja que voce nao faz o uso de update seu trigger nao vai ter problem com "on
 conflit", Trigger vai ser usado apenas na tabela pai para redirecionar os insert.

3-  Table partition nao divide tabela apenas por data!!! voce pode usar alguma codicao mas elaborada, ou seja "semelhança entre eles".

Como vai ficar seu db, exemplo:

```
TabelaMaster (Tabela original)
TabelaMaster-10 (Tabela gerada apartir do INHERITS )
TabelaMaster-20
...
```

os selects podem ser feitos diretamento na particao ou na tabela "pai" o resultado e quase a mesma coisa, porem usar o pai evitar extra codigo.

Comment: Olá @HudsonPH, não acho que Table Partition seria interessante já que, no meu caso, tenho uma lista imensa de indivíduos com similaridades bem concentradas entre 40 e 80%, o que dividiria a tabela em partes não tão interessantes (ainda estou pensando em usar a técnica mencionada no comentário anterior em junção com partition).
Obrigado!

Comment: Voce pode ate testar, mas o refresh view no seu caso vai ter um custo muito alto afinal de contas sao 3 trilhoes que vao ser lidos e substituidos todos os dias na view